# Xcode, Fold group of codes under certain method/ function with a simple click

Tags: swift, xcode, folding

I Have a multiple if else statements under another if else statements and I want to be able to fold all child statements under certain parent without have to fold each one separately cause its like 100's of them.
For Example (Just a generic code, it can be anything else):

the code Unfolded

```
func example(v1: String, v2: Int, v3: Int)
{
    if v1 == "Food"
    {
        if v2 == 2 && v3 == 7
        {
            // Some Long Lines Codes
        }
        else if v2 == 2 && v3 == 33
        {
            // Some Long Lines Codes
        }
        else if v2 == 44 && v3 == 72
        {
            // Some Long Lines Codes
        }
        else if v2 == 12 && v3 == 7
        {
            // Some Long Lines Codes
        }
        else if v2 == 102 && v3 == 97
        {
            // Some Long Lines Codes
        }
    }
}
```

And I Wanted To Be Folded Like That With A Simple Click Not Fold It One By One

```
func example(v1: String, v2: Int, v3: Int)
{
    if v1 == "Food"
    {
        if v2 == 2 && v3 == 7
        {...}
        else if v2 == 2 && v3 == 33
        {...}
        else if v2 == 44 && v3 == 72
        {...}
        else if v2 == 12 && v3 == 7
        {...}
        else if v2 == 102 && v3 == 97
        {...}
    }
}
```

Imaging like 100 lines of those else if conditions that i need to fold each one manually using CMD + Opt + <-  or even using the arrow beside, I hope there is a fast and reliable shortcut or a click to help folding child codes or selected codes

btw I know there is a cmd + opt + shift + <- to fold all but that's not helping cause when I unfold the function I would see all remains as it was before.

I hope anyone could have a clue or if there is an ability to add a script function to do so.

Comment: Wanting to do all this folding is perhaps a sign that your code is not structured as well as it could be. For one, the most common swift code style is to put the `{` and `} else if … {` on one line. Each of those long lines of code you omitted from the question could be moved to a separate (and well-named) handler function. A switch may be better than a long list of checks of the same two variables for different values.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, In fact this code I put is just an example not related at all to what I code, I just ask a generic question if this is possible in Xcode till version 14.3 or not. and may be to encourage apple to may be add function to fold selected parts. but thanx for your reply